# How to write condition in route in angular / ionic

Tags: angular, router, ionic5

I'm using **ionic 5** framework to build an application , I want to add condition in route if user already signed in before change route .

**app-routing.module.ts** file :

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'home',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
        path: 'home',
        loadChildren: './home/home.module#HomePageModule'
    },
    {
        path: 'doctors',
        loadChildren: () => import('./doctors/doctors.module').then(m => m.DoctorsPageModule)
    },
    {
        path: 'dashboard',
        loadChildren: () => import('./user/dashboard/dashboard.module').then(m => m.DashboardPageModule),
        canLoad: [AuthGuard],
    },
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules})
    ],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

I want to add **condition** here :

```
       {
            path: '',
            redirectTo: 'home',
            pathMatch: 'full'
        },
```

if user already signed change `redirectTo: 'home'` to be `redirectTo: 'dashboard'` how can i do this ?

> Note : I'm used `AuthGuard` to prevent user from signed into some
> routs

Comment: Are you manage any localstorage for check that user is signed in or not ?

Comment: @RohitTagadiya Yes i did . and i used `AuthGuard`  to check it .

Comment: Then after sign in if you are getting token then you can store it in localstorage and when ever you come into `home` page, check that if token is stored in localstorage then redirect to `dashboard` otherwise, need to login...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use your AuthGuard, but the **canActivate** function, like this:

**Routes:**

```
 {
     path: 'dashboard',
     loadChildren: () => import('./user/dashboard/dashboard.module').then(m => m.DashboardPageModule),
     canLoad: [AuthGuard],
     canActivate: [AuthGuard]
 },
```

**AuthGuard**

```
constructor(private router:Router) {}

canLoad = () => {//...your code }

canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
   if (!isLoggedIn()) { //your verification to logged In
       
      this.router.navigate(['/']);
      return false;
    }
    return true;   
}
```

Finally, in your HomeComponent, you redirect in case if loggedIn.

**HomeComponent.ts**

```
ngOnInit(): void {
   if(isLoggedIn()) this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);
}
```

Comment: What the different between `canActivate` and `canLoad`

Comment: canActivate is used to prevent unauthorized users from accessing certain routes. 

canLoad is used to prevent the application from loading entire modules lazily if the user is not authorized to do so.

Answer (score 2):

```
/***** gaurd */

@Injectable()
export class checkLogged {
  canActivate() {
    //check user is logged in
  }
}

const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'dashboard',
        pathMatch: 'full', 
        canActivate: [checkLogged]
    },
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'home',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
        path: 'home',
        loadChildren: './home/home.module#HomePageModule'
    },
    {
        path: 'doctors',
        loadChildren: () => import('./doctors/doctors.module').then(m => m.DoctorsPageModule)
    },
    {
        path: 'dashboard',
        loadChildren: () => import('./user/dashboard/dashboard.module').then(m => m.DashboardPageModule),
        canLoad: [AuthGuard],
    },
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules})
    ],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a resolver to solve this problem like `TestResolverService`:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Resolve, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from '@core/services/auth/auth.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class TestResolverService implements Resolve<any> {
  constructor(private router: Router, public authService: AuthService) {}

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<any> | Promise<any> | any {
// or anyhow you specify if user is signed in or not 
    return this.authService.subjectUser.pipe(
      map((user) => {
        const isAuth = !!user;
        if (isAuth) {
          this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
        } else {
          this.router.navigate(['/home']);
          return false;
        }
      })
    );
  }
}
```

And in your routerModule:

```
{ path: '', resolve: { TestResolverService }, children: [] },
{
    path: 'home',
    loadChildren: './home/home.module#HomePageModule'
},
{
    path: 'doctors',
    loadChildren: () => import('./doctors/doctors.module').then(m => m.DoctorsPageModule)
},
{
    path: 'dashboard',
    loadChildren: () => import('./user/dashboard/dashboard.module').then(m => m.DashboardPageModule),
    canLoad: [AuthGuard],
},
```

Answer (score 2):

The auth guard is an angular route guard that's used to prevent unauthenticated or unauthorized users from accessing restricted routes, it does this by implementing the **CanActivate** interface which allows the guard to decide if a route can be activated with the **canActivate()** method. If the method returns true the route is activated (allowed to proceed), otherwise if the method returns false the route is blocked.

The auth guard uses the authentication service to check if the user is logged in, if they are logged in it checks if their role is authorized to access the requested route. If they are logged in and authorized the **canActivate()** method returns true, otherwise it returns false and redirects the user to the login page.

Angular route guards are attached to routes in the router config, this auth guard is used in **app.routing.ts** to protect the home page and admin page routes.

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';

import { AuthenticationService } from '@app/_services';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private authenticationService: AuthenticationService
    ) { }

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
        const currentUser = this.authenticationService.currentUserValue;
        if (currentUser) {
            // check if route is restricted by role
            if (route.data.roles && route.data.roles.indexOf(currentUser.role) === -1) {
                // role not authorised so redirect to home page
                this.router.navigate(['/']);
                return false;
            }

            // authorised so return true
            return true;
        }

        // not logged in so redirect to login page with the return url
        this.router.navigate(['/login'], { queryParams: { returnUrl: state.url } });
        return false;
    }
}
```